# Restoring a removed git repository

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm new to git and I've made a couple of commits to local repo. Then by mistake I clicked 'Pull' instead of 'Push'. In the end I starded to cleaning my desktop... I removed a whole directory (repo clone). After cloning repo from server there wasn't any of my commits.

Could you tell me please is it possible to restore removed repo (changes)? I'm using Windows 7 + TortoiseGit.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you backing up your local machine? If not, when will you start?

Here's the bottom line: if you have changes in your local repo that you don't push, and then you delete that repo, the fact that your changes were once in a source control system can't help you.

Comment: Yes, it's local machine. I tried to recover it using lc-tech filerecovery. It didn't helped me. Most of the files were already overwritten. I belved that there's some git cache... :)
Anyway I'm 5 hours back in my work.
That's why I prefer svn...

Comment: @Wtq - There was, but you deleted it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Response to comment:

I'm not surprised that you have been using SVN (cvs-isch). It's essential that you learn the difference between commit and commit. In git you only commit locally and use the push/pull mechanism to synchronize different repositories that have diverged from each other.

The commit in git can be looked as some form of cached commit in SVN, you queue up your changes for a later synchronization. The actual sync is delayed. A lot of people at work still have problems getting the difference

---

Original answer:

Version control is not a cure for stupidity ;) The only thing you can do is to try and recover data from the hard drive by hiring someone that can reconstruct data that has been lost.

Comment: @Wtq: If you kill a SVN-repo its exactly the same :)

Comment: @KingCrunch - Using SVN I send changes to remote server, not to local HDD... :)

Comment: @Wtq: Like I said: If you kill a (remote, because its always remote) SVN-repo its exactly the same. _No_ VCS replaces a backup.

Comment: Hey guys. Please see my revised answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You committed to your local repository, not the server. If you deleted that repository, there's no way to get the commits back from a repository you didn't commit to. Version control can only do so much...

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know for next time, you probably wanted something like `git reset --hard @{1}` to put your local repository back to the state it was before the accidental pull.